# 3 most popular conversions from dictionary in c#

Tags: c#

im trying to figure out why doesn't it work. i have simple app - converter app. there are 6 ways to convert some units e.g. Fahrenheit to Celsius, Celsius to Fahrenheit. On click "2" in main menu, app should show 3 most popular conversions but i see only 2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class PopularConversions
    {
        public static void ReadLogs()
        {
            var popularConversions = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            var conversions = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
                { "Fahrenheit -> Celsjusz", 0 },
                { "Celsjusz -> Fahrenheit", 0 },
                { "Mila -> Kilometr", 0 },
                { "Kilometr -> Mila", 0 },
                { "Funt -> Kilogram", 0 },
                { "Kilogram -> Funt", 0 },
            };

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("stats.txt");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string from = line.Split("|")[2];
                string to = line.Split("|")[3];

                if (from == "Funt" && to == "Kilogram")
                    conversions["Funt -> Kilogram"]++;
                else if (from == "Kilogram" && to == "Funt")
                    conversions["Kilogram -> Funt"]++;
                else if (from == "Mila" && to == "Kilometr")
                    conversions["Mila -> Kilometr"]++;
                else if (from == "Kilometr" && to == "Mila")
                    conversions["Kilometr -> Mila"]++;
                else if (from == "Fahrenheit" && to == "Celsjusz")
                    conversions["Fahrenheit -> Celsjusz"]++;
                else if (from == "Celsjusz" && to == "Fahrenheit")
                    conversions["Celsjusz -> Fahrenheit"]++;
            } 

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                string result = "Funt -> Kilogram";
                foreach (string key in conversions.Keys)
                {
                    if (!popularConversions.ContainsKey(key) && conversions[result] < conversions[key])
                        result = key;
                }
                popularConversions.TryAdd(result, conversions[result]);
            }

            foreach (string key in popularConversions.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + key + ": " + popularConversions[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: conversions.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Value).Take(3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the file in your question or better inline it in your code.

You algorithm doesn't make sense. If "funt -> kilogram" is the most popular conversion, you will end up "TryAdd"ing it to the popularConversions over and over, so you would end up with a single entry in your popularConversions.

What you need to do is to sort the conversions entries and take the top 3. I don't have time to do it but something along the lines of:

```cs
var convList = conversions.ToList();
convList.Sort((kvp1, kvp2) => { return kvp1.Value.CompareTo(kvp2.Value); });
convList.Take(3).ToList().ForEach(kvp => {
    Console.WriteLine("\n" + kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
});
```